# How to get the Framework's path when the project is a Framework project in iOS?

Tags: ios, path, frameworks

Normally if I create a Framework in an app project, I can get the framework's path from, NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath + "Frameworks/FrameworkName.Framework".

However, if I create a pure Framework project, as there is no app in it. I can not get the path of the framework, as the NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath is always "`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Agents`".

What should I do?

Comment: Why do you need framework path when in framework project, its required when you link you framework in a project.

Comment: I have resource file need to load in the framework. I have unit test with the framework's functions.